# How to read data in parquet gzip format from S3 using R?

Tags: r, amazon-s3

I want to fetch my data from s3 to my local R environment, but that data store in parquet gzip format. Also need to write that data and store in s3. Basically read/write operation on parquet gzip format using R.

My s3 looks like -

```
Bucket List- 
a
b
c
d
hh
```

Then select "c" bucket
Then select "Audit" folder, on that folder I want to extract "test_gzip.parquet" file. So final path looks like -

```
Bucket List >> c >> Audit
```

How to manage it in R?
Thanks in advance

Comment: [aws.s3](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/aws.s3/README.html) might just suit your use case where the eight main functions under `Objects` category will be useful for working with objects in S3

Comment: Is there any update regarding my query?